# How to calculate GRASS covariance matrices in QGIS with r.covar?

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, grass-gis

I would like to calculate covariance matrices **between** different bands of the same raster in QGIS (2 or 3). I have found only one built-in processing tool capable of doing this, named [r.covar](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.covar.html) from GRASS.

Unfortunately, in QGIS this tool is structured to only accept "entire" raster layers as input, while in GRASS it is indeed possible to calculate covariance matrices between bands of the same raster dataset.

I have tried to trick PyQGIS to accepting GDAL's bands as inputs, but it only accepts raster layers. Does anyone have a solution to this problem or perhaps a user script that does creates covariance and correlation matrices?

I would strongly prefer **not** to save each band as a separate file strictly for this problem.

Sample code:

```
import processing,gdal

rasterLayer = iface.activeLayer()
ds = gdal.Open("C:\\Multispectral_Clipped.tif")

outputRaster= "C:\\Output.html"
extent =rasterLayer.extent()

xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()

#Not working option
output=processing.runalg('grass7:r.covar', [ds.GetRasterBand(1),ds.GetRasterBand(2), ds.GetRasterBand(3)],True,"%f,%f,%f,%f" %(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),outputRaster,None)

#Working option
output=processing.runalg('grass7:r.covar', [rasterLayer],True,"%f,%f,%f,%f" %(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),outputRaster,None)
```

**EDIT**
I suspect my request above is not possible. So the question is then just how to run r.covar with multiple inputs in PyQGIS (QGIS 2.18)?

Even with having the line:

```
output=processing.runalg('grass7:r.covar', [rasterList],True,"%f,%f,%f,%f" %(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),outputHtml,outputRaw)
```

And the rasterList containing a Python list like so: `['C:\\band1.tiff', 'C:\\band2.tiff', 'C:\\band3.tiff']`

I am getting a `Wrong parameter value` error. I've also tried loading them as QgsRasterLayer, like done [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144058/loading-raster-layer-using-pyqgis) with the StringToRaster function, but got the same error.

Comment: How did you define `outputHtml` and `outputRaw`? Does it work if you replace these with `None`?

Comment: These are simply defined as paths, e.g. `outputHtml = "C:\\correlation_output.html"` and `outputRaw = "C:\\correlation_output.txt"`. I tried replacing them with `None`, it still doesn't work. Furthermore, the error says `Wrong parameter value: ['C:\\band1.tiff', 'C:\\band2.tiff', 'C:\\band3.tiff']`, pointing to the input error there.

Comment: Which extension are the rasters. `.tif` or `.tiff`?

Comment: They are .tiff files, saved from an original composite 'tif' file using this little loop: 
`for i in range (1,ds.RasterCount+1): 
    srcband = ds.GetRasterBand(i)
    out_ds = gdal.Translate(out_path + 'band' + str(i) + '.tiff', ds, format='GTiff', bandList=[i])
    out_ds=None`
I tried saving them as .tif, but got the same error. Also, r.covar works in the interface with the rasters, both as .tif or tiff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem was in the order of the **extent** variables, as well as the `rasterList` variable type and format. Here is the corrected code:

```
def getRasterExtent(raster_path):
    src = gdal.Open(raster_path)
    ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres  = src.GetGeoTransform()
    lrx = ulx + (src.RasterXSize * xres)
    lry = uly + (src.RasterYSize * yres)
    return [ulx,lrx,lry,uly] #xmin, xmax,ymin,ymax


rasterList=[]
extent=[]
for filename in os.listdir(input_dir): #Loop over all individual single band rasters in a folder and create correlation matrix
    if filename.endswith(".tif"): 
        rasterPath = os.path.join(input_dir, filename)
        rasterList.append(rasterPath)
        extent =getRasterExtent(rasterPath)


rasterString =str( ";".join(rasterList)) #convert the list of raster paths to a *semicolon* seperated STRING (the way GDAL expects it).
xmin,xmax,ymax,ymin = extent[0],extent[1],extent[2],extent[3]

output=processing.runalg('grass7:r.covar', rasterString,True,"%f,%f,%f,%f" %(xmin, xmax, ymax, ymin),None,None)
```

So this works and creates a correlation matrix from a given directory of single-band, same extent, rasters.