# Output layer doesn't get created

Tags: raster, pyqgis

Why isn't my heat layer valid and I don't get a `.tif` in this location (this location exists 100%)? Code below:

```
output = "D:/QGIS_Project_New/heat_map_last.tif"
heat = QgsRasterLayer(output, "Heatmap")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([heat])
if heat.isValid() is True:
print "Layer was loaded successfully!"
else:
print "Unable to read basename and file path - Your string is invalid"
```

I get the `"Unable.."` `print`, why is that?

EDIT:

So my code for loading layers is working:

```
highway_layer = QgsVectorLayer("D:/Tomas/QGIS_Project_New/points_highway.shp","Highway","ogr")

if highway_layer.isValid() is True:
    print " HIGHWAY Layer was loaded successfully!"
else:
    print " HIGHWAY Unable to read basename and file path - Your string is invalid"
```

But when I try to create and save a layer on this location it is not working. Also I'm using Python Console in QGIS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading raster layer using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144058/loading-raster-layer-using-pyqgis)

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @JohnDoe! How are you running your code, from a script or from the python console? Can you confirm that the file is indeed in the directory you specified?

Comment: I've read that post, my loading is correct and I use this in my code before this code:

highway_layer = QgsVectorLayer("D:/Tomas/QGIS_Project_New/points_highway.shp","Highway","ogr")
if highway_layer.isValid() is True:
    print " HIGHWAY Layer was loaded successfully!"
else:
    print " HIGHWAY Unable to read basename and file path - Your string is invalid"

And I get  " HIGHWAY Layer was loaded successfully!"

 I'm running the code from the qgis python console.

Comment: Please add any additional clarifications and code to your question by editing it.

Comment: Did it just now. I'm trying to SAVE in my first example, loading in my second example is working.

Comment: Does "D:/QGIS_Project_New/heat_map_last.tif" exist? it looks like you're trying to add an existing tif to a map, and the file isn't found.

Comment: No it doesn't? I want to create it in the end.

Check: Source of code(Page 272): http://www.green-forums.info/greenlib/geolibrary/Lawhead%20J/QGIS%20Python%20Programming%20Cookbook.%2020%20%2852%29/QGIS%20Python%20Programming%20Cookboo%20-%20Lawhead%20J.pdf

Comment: @smiller Hi, yes I understand now, I thought I was creating heatmap in this code  but actually I just have to import my heatmap from the process beforehand.

Please help with my further issue: 

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319254/kernel-density-estimation-weighting-factor?noredirect=1#comment519881_319254