# Kernel Density Estimation Weighting Factor

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, density

I don't understand where is this weighting factor coming from, does it need to be in the `quakeLyr` in the attribute table named with `"mag"` or?

```
# Now, we can run the kernel density estimation algorithm by specifying the mag or magnitude field as our weighting factor:

processing.runalg("saga:kerneldensityestimation", quakeLyr, "mag", 10, 0, 0, box, 1, output)
```

[Source of code](http://www.green-forums.info/greenlib/geolibrary/Lawhead%20J/QGIS%20Python%20Programming%20Cookbook.%2020%20%2852%29/QGIS%20Python%20Programming%20Cookboo%20-%20Lawhead%20J.pdf#page=272)

Comment: No, you just specify the name of the field inside the layer you are running the tool on which contains the weighting values.

Comment: When you say name of the field, what do you mean exactly, what field? Where can I find that field if not in the attribute table?

Comment: The name of the field (or column) inside your attribute table.

Answer (score 1):

The "weight" parameter for the SAGA Kernel Density Estimation tool has to be set to one of the fields of the input point layer. This can easily be determined by looking at the graphic user interface of the tool:

[image]