# Loading raster from WMS in a QGIS Plugin

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, wms

(I have since found a solution and added it as an answer)

I am currently creating my first Plugin for QGIS using the 'Plugin Builder'Plugin, QtDesigner and Python. At this point it's just supposed to create a raster layer from WMS for the extent of a chosen layer and a 1km zone around it.

The wms_url I get via the print command works both in the QGIS WMS menu and the browser
([example](https://uas-betrieb.de/geoservices/dipul/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=dipul:wohngrundstuecke&bbox=590685,%205460870,%20602547,%205472999&width=11862&height=12129&srs=EPSG:25832&transparent=true&format=image/png&styles=)), the layer created using it in the next line isn't valid however and I can't figure out why.

1. Imports etc:
   (The last 3 lines are from the top answer of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144058/loading-raster-layer-in-a-standalone-pyqgis-script) as it seems to be the same issue, it didn't solve anything for me though.)

```py
from os import system
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction, QFileDialog
from qgis.core import *
import processing
from .resources import *
from .flight_planner_dialog import UASFlightPlannerDialog
import os.path
qgis_prefix="C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.26.3\\apps\\qgis"
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgis_prefix, True) 
QgsApplication.initQgis()
```

(I skipped some stuff generated by the Plugin Builder (and I think QtDesigner) here)

2. Context for the variables in the WMS URL (shouldn't be the issue, but just in case):

```py
flightpath = self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()
destCrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(25832)
flightpathCrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(flightpath.crs())
ext = flightpath.extent()
if destCrs != flightpathCrs:
         tform = QgsCoordinateTransform(flightpathCrs, destCrs, QgsProject.instance())
         ext = tform.transform(ext)
bboxwest = round(ext.xMinimum())-1000
bboxsouth = round(ext.yMinimum())-1000
bboxeast = round(ext.xMaximum())+1000
bboxnorth = round(ext.yMaximum())+1000
height = bboxnorth-bboxsouth
width = bboxeast-bboxwest
```

3. The part that doesn't work:

```py
wms_url = 'url=https://uas-betrieb.de/geoservices/dipul/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=dipul:wohngrundstuecke&bbox='+str(bboxwest)+','+str(bboxsouth)+','+str(bboxeast)+','+str(bboxnorth)+'&width='+str(width)+'&height='+str(height)+'&srs=EPSG:25832&transparent=true&format=image/png&styles='
print (wms_url)
rgeozones = QgsRasterLayer(wms_url, 'rgeozones', 'wms')
print(rgeozones.isValid())
```

Comment: I can't find the question just now, but yesterday there was a similar question (with a WFS, I believe) and the solution was to remove `url=` from the beginning of the `wms_url` string.

Comment: May not affect you for this WMS but note that bbox for WMS is in minx,miny,maxx,maxy order where x is the first listed axis in the CRS and y the second, it isn't always west,south,east,north

Comment: also note the values for `transparent` are `TRUE` or `FALSE` i.e. case sensitive, the default value is false, so `transparent=true` may give a non-transparent image

Comment: for  WMS version 1.3.0 you should use `CRS` not `SRS` to define the coordinate reference system

Comment: @Matt thanks for the suggestion, but removing the `url=` just adds a error message for me. Translated to english it would be something like:
"Property request failed: The protocol "" is unknown"
From what I could find online, `url=` is for some reason needed for WMS, but not for WFS.

@nmtoken thank you as well, I applied your suggestions, however it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: In service `https://uas-betrieb.de/geoservices/dipul/wms` according to the GetCapabilities response, there is no layer called `dipul:wohngrundstuecke` there is a layer called `wohngrundstuecke`  That layer doesn't support the CRS that you are requesting, you can use only one of `EPSG:4326,EPSG:3857,EPSG:7789,CRS:84`.

Comment: The final thing to consider I think will be the size of your calculated width and   height.  - if you took a request like `https://uas-betrieb.de/geoservices/dipul/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=653740.1014785182197,5993688.218827254139,1673555.295759583823,7371373.09475582093&CRS=EPSG:3857&WIDTH=486&HEIGHT=657&LAYERS=wohngrundstuecke&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE` your width and height calculations would result in an image that was order of magnitudes too big, and I would guess never returned by the server

Comment: @nmtoken Can the issue even be the URL, considering it works just fine when put into a web browser as it is? 

As for your suggestions: According to the how-to part of their website, you are supposed to add `dipul:` in front of the layer names, though I have found it working both ways. I wondered about the CRS before, but again, the server seems to handle it just fine as it gives out the correct area when requested via a web browser. Cutting down on width and height doesn't change anything either.

Comment: running out of ideas.  Are you certain that your code generates the example request?

Comment: @nmtoken Thank you for your efforts, I have found a solution and added it to the bottom of the question. You were right about the `dipul:` and I failed to give the information necessary to figure out the other problem.

Comment: You should add your solution edit as an answer to your question (and accept it).  As an aside, for WMS (and I think all the OGC interface standards using OWS common) the syntax for any parameter is `key=value&` not `&key=value` where `=value` is optional, so an empty styles parameter would be `styles&` not `&styles=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL needs a slightly different syntax in Python than in both the web browser and the WMS menu in QGIS. There were two seperate issues:

1. @nmtoken was indeed right, the `dipul:` breaks it, but only in Python.
2. In my actual Code I request about a dozen layers, not just one. I omitted this detail in the question because I thought it was irrelevant and just reduced readability.
   While in the web browser and the menu you can simply seperate them with a comma
   `&layers=layername1,layername2,layername3&styles&`, in python you have to call each one seperately
   `&layers=layername1&layers=layername2&layers=layername3&styles&styles&styles&`. There also has to be the same amount of `styles&` as `layers=layername&`.

So the relevant bit now looks like this:
Note that the URL produced by this code doesn't work in web browsers/the WMS menu.

```
wms_url = 'url=https://uas-betrieb.de/geoservices/dipul/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=flugplaetze&styles&layers=flughaefen&styles&layers=kontrollzonen&styles&layers=flugbeschraenkungsgebiete&styles&layers=bundesautobahnen&styles&layers=bundesstrassen&styles&layers=bahnanlagen&styles&layers=binnenwasserstrassen&styles&layers=seewasserstrassen&styles&layers=schifffahrtsanlagen&styles&layers=wohngrundstuecke&styles&layers=freibaeder&styles&layers=industrieanlagen&styles&layers=kraftwerke&styles&layers=umspannwerke&styles&layers=stromleitungen&styles&layers=windkraftanlagen&styles&layers=justizvollzugsanstalten&styles&layers=militaerische_anlagen&styles&layers=labore&styles&layers=verfassungsorgane&styles&layers=oberste_behoerden&styles&layers=diplomatische_vertretungen&styles&layers=internationale_organisationen&styles&layers=polizei&styles&layers=sicherheitsbehoerden&styles&layers=krankenhaeuser&styles&layers=nationalparks&styles&layers=naturschutzgebiete&styles&layers=ffh-gebiete&styles&layers=vogelschutzgebiete&styles&bbox='+str(xMin)+','+str(yMin)+','+str(xMax)+','+str(yMax)+'&width='+str(width)+'&height='+str(height)+'&crs=EPSG:3857&transparent=TRUE&format=image/png&'
print(wms_url)
rgeozones = QgsRasterLayer(wms_url, 'rgeozones', 'wms')
rgeozones.setExtent(QgsRectangle(xMin,yMin,xMax,yMax))
```

The `.setExtent()` is needed because QGIS doesn't seem to care about my bounding box. It basically just crops the image.
I also changed the CRS to one that matches the `GetCapabilities`, however it still also works with `EPSG: 25832`.

Even before these changes I didn't get any actual error messages, it just didn't do anything. However with `print (rgeozones.error().message())` I was able to find out, why the layer wasn't valid. I couldn't find a fix for this online, so I hope this post may help someone. It turned out to be because of the second issue.
Error message:

```
WMS provider: Cannot calculate extent 
Raster layer: Provider is not valid (provider: wms, URI: <the uri of the wms request>)
```